# How to make list view which goes in next line after overflow and only one item should be selectable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to android development and encountered an issue while development. First of all look at the design which I want to make.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17YYz.jpg

In the image, the size list is fetched from the server and shown, but here what I want is that suppose another size `11` is given then it should automatically move to the next line. So what I know that recycler view can't be used here. Now how can I achieve this also another point is that how can I make that only one item is selected from the collection of the sizes and selecting another size should de-select the previously selected size. Please provide me some good way to achieve both the targets inefficient way.

Comment: `then it should automatically move to next line` search for `FlowLayout`. `only one item is selected ... and selecting other size should de-select previous` use `RadioButtons` + `RadioGroup`. To make `RadioButton` loot like `TextView` set it's button drawable to `null`, and create a selector for it's background for `selected` state

Answer (score 0):

To Achive this view . you can use recyclerview with `GridLayoutManager` . in gridview we have set number of item is one row . try this code to achive this view. in this code i have used a recycler view with a gridview . in this code i have implement only one item select check .

**CODE**

> FirstActivity

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   RecyclerView recycler_view;
   GridLayoutManager manager;
   static  int selectItem=-1;
   CustomAdapter customAdapter;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
      initView();
   }

   private void initView(){
      ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
      list.add("8");
      list.add("10");
      list.add("11");
      list.add("12");
      list.add("14");
      list.add("16");
      list.add("18");
      recycler_view=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
      manager=new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
      recycler_view.setLayoutManager(manager);
        customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this, list);
      recycler_view.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   }
}
```

> CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyHolder>{
   Context context;
   ArrayList<String> dataList;


   public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataList, ){
      this.context=context;
      this.dataList=dataList;

   }

   @NonNull

   @Override
   public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
      View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_custom,viewGroup,false);
      MyHolder myHolder=new MyHolder(view);
      return myHolder;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, final int i){
      //check select item position
      if(selectItem==i){
         myHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      }else {
         myHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      }
    myHolder.textView.setText(dataList.get(i));
    myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
          selectItem=i;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    });
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount(){
      return dataList.size();
   }

   public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
      public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
         super(itemView);
         textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_tv);
      }
   }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

I Hope It work for you, if any query comment me